Given $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain, prove that period $d = \gcd\{n \in \mathbb{N} : p_{j,j}^{(n)} > 0\}$.
Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov chain on a state space $E$. Assume $j\in E$ with $f_{j,j}>0$ where $E$ denotes the state space and $f_{j,j}$ denotes the probability of starting in $j$ and eventually returning to $j$. Let the period $d\ge 1$ be the greatest integer such that
\begin{equation}\label{eq:def-period}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=kd)+\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=\infty)=1,
\end{equation}
where $T_1^{(j)}=\min\{n\ge 1: X_n=j\}$ is the first return time to $j$. Prove that for a state $j$ with $f_{j,j}>0$, we have
$$
d = \gcd\{n \in \mathbb{N} : p_{j,j}^{(n)} > 0\}.
$$
My attempt: since by the assumption of $f_{j,j}>0$, it follows that
$
\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=\infty)=0.
$
By the definition of $d$, we have
$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=kd)=1.
$. Let $R=\{n\in\mathbb{N}| p_{j,j}^{(n)}>0\}$ denote the set of all return times. We aim to show $d\mathbb{N}=R$ via proving $R\subseteq d\mathbb{N}$ and $d\mathbb{N}\subseteq R$, separately. But I can find an example showing that $d\mathbb{N}\supset R$, i.e. $R$ is a proper set of $d\mathbb{N}$. I guess that for large $n$, the two sets will align. Any ideas? I was aware that many textbooks directly use the claim here as the definition of period.

Put "Markov chain" somewhere in the starting text of your question. Also the title. Tags are not for human readers, they are for computer sorting.  Humans shouldn't have to jump tot the bottom and read the tags to figure out the context.

Thanks for reminding me.

"since by the assumption of $f_{j,j}>0$, it follows that
$
\mathbb{P}j(T_1^{(j)}=\infty)=0.
$". This argument is false because given $f{j,j}>0$, $
\mathbb{P}j(T_1^{(j)}=\infty)
$ is not necessarily 0. If $f{j,j}=1$, then that statement is true. So, my attempt is not correct.

I am not 100% sure the following proof is correct. Please correct me if somewhere is incorrect.
The definition of $d$ is given by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:def period}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=kd)+\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=\infty)=1. \tag{*}
\end{equation}
Let $R=\{n\in\mathbb{N}| p_{j,j}^{(n)}>0\}$ denote the set of all return times. To show $d=\mathrm{gcd}(R)$, we equivalently show the following:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:equiv-d}
m \text{ is a common divisor of } R \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=km)+\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(j)}=\infty)=1. \tag{**}
\end{equation}
Step 1: Show $\Longrightarrow$.
If $m$ is a common divisor of $R$, then for any $n$ with $p_{j,j}^{(n)}>0$, we can write $n=k\cdot m$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. By the definition of $T_1^{(km)}$, $T_1^{(km)}$ denotes the event that the chain returns to $j$ at time $km$ for the first time. $p_{j,j}^{(km)}$ denotes the probability that the chain returns to $j$ at time $km$, which includes more paths to return $j$, but $\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{km})$ only includes one possibility. It follows that $p_{j,j}^{(km)}\ge \mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{km})$. In other words, if $\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(km)})>0$, then $p_{j,j}^{(km)}>0$. Therefore,
$$
\{km\in\mathbb{N}|\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(km)})>0\}\subseteq \{km\in\mathbb{N}|p_{j,j}^{(km)}>0\}.
$$
This shows that if $p_{j,j}^{(km)}>0$, i.e., m is a common divisor of $R$, the RHS of \eqref{eq:equiv-d} holds.
Step 2: Show $\Longleftarrow$.
Let $M$ be the set of all natural numbers that satisfies the periodicity condition in \eqref{eq:def period}. We aim to show that if $m\in M$ then m is a common divisor of $R$. The trivial case of $m=1$ is always true, because $m=1$ always satisfies the RHS of \eqref{eq:equiv-d} and $1$ is definitely a common divisor of all natural numbers. Note that the trivial case includes all the possibilities: $\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(km)})=0$ and $\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(km)})>0$.
Actually, the former possibility does not affect the RHS of \eqref{eq:equiv-d}, we only need to check that if there exists some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(km)})>0$, then $m$ is a common divisor of $R$. Indeed, since $\mathbb{P}_j(T_1^{(km)})>0$ means the first return time could be $km$, it follows that $p_{j,j}^{(km)}>0$ is also true, because there is already a return path.
Since we have shown both directions, the greatest $m$ on the LHS is exactly equal to the greatest $m$ on the RHS, namely $\mathrm{gcd}(R)=d$. This completes the proof.

I suggest that you edit the part where you wrote "therefore,..." before step number 2

@DavideMasi Thanks for the suggestion. I already edited it.
